# What is the difference between mongoose.ObjectId and mongoose.Types.ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

It's mentioned in the docs the following:

> An ObjectId is a special type typically used for unique identifiers...

```
const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ driver: mongoose.ObjectId });
```

> **ObjectId** is a class, and ObjectIds are objects....etc

```
const Car = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);

const car = new Car();
car.driver = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

typeof car.driver; // 'object'
car.driver instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId; // true

car.driver.toString(); // Something like "5e1a0651741b255ddda996c4"
```

What is meant by ObjectId (the bold text above in the quote)? is it `mongoose.ObjectId` or `mongoose.Types.ObjectId?`

And what's the difference between them?

The URL of the docs:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#usage-notes

at the ObjectIds section

Answer (score 0):

According to [schema types docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

> A SchemaType is different from a type. In other words, mongoose.ObjectId !== mongoose.Types.ObjectId. A SchemaType is just a configuration object for Mongoose. An instance of the mongoose.ObjectId SchemaType doesn't actually create MongoDB ObjectIds, it is just a configuration for a path in a schema.

Also into docs:

> You can think of a Mongoose schema as the configuration object for a Mongoose model. A SchemaType is then a configuration object for an individual property. A SchemaType says what type a given path should have, whether it has any getters/setters, and what values are valid for that path.

So, `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` is a "mongoose object" while `mongoose.ObjectId` is a "mongodb object".

Edit to answer the comments.

To the first question, for me is: Yes. As a developer that use mongoose I only use mongoose functions. That implies use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of `mongoose.ObjectId`.

Also if you try to do `mongoose.ObjectId()` you will get a warning 'To create a new ObjectId please try `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of using `Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`'

About the second question, if I've understood correctly, yes too. You can check this.

Create a new schema and do:

```js
const MongooseModel = new mongoose.Schema({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId})

MongooseModel.path('_id') instanceof mongoose.Schema.ObjectId // true
MongooseModel.path('_id') instanceof mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId // true
MongooseModel.path('_id') instanceof mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId // true
MongooseModel.path('_id') instanceof mongoose.ObjectId // true
MongooseModel.path('_id').instance // ObjectID

MongooseModel.path('_id') instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId // false
mongoose.Schema.ObjectId instanceof mongoose.Types.ObjectId // false
```

Your schema `_id` is created via `mongoose.Types` and is instance of `mongoose.ObjectId`. Also is not an instance of the type, as explained into docs "A SchemaType is different from a type".

The `_id` generated is an instance of the `ObjectID` but is not an instance of the "parent" who generates the value.

Comment: So in other words, we developers only use mongoose.Types.ObjectId, while mongoose.ObjectId is in most of the time only consumed by mongoose and not by us. correct me if I'm misunderstanding it, have you ever used mongoose.ObjectId? if yes, in which scenarios?

Comment: according to my understand: invoking mongoose.Types.ObjectId() will return a mongoose.ObjectId, correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

So in other words, we developers only use mongoose.Types.ObjectId, while mongoose.ObjectId is in most of the time only consumed by mongoose and not by us. correct me if I'm misunderstanding it, have you ever used mongoose.ObjectId? if yes, in which scenarios? – Ekmek

Ekmek - I have some experience with this.  The reason for the mongoose object Id in this way is to 'pre-fetch' a unique id.  Instead of waiting for mongodb to take the new doc and issue an Id, we can use mongoose to create a key for us and save the waiting step.  This is useful when you want the new id but don't have time to wait for mongodb to give you one.  ...I just can't remember if I had to configure something to tell mongodb not to worry.

Answer (score 0):

> What is meant by ObjectId (the bold text above in the quote)? is it mongoose.ObjectId or mongoose.Types.ObjectId?

It is `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` which is the bson type according to docs.

> And what's the difference between them?

The distinction lies in their roles and functionalities. `mongoose.ObjectId` is the Mongoose ObjectId SchemaType, serving as a configuration object within a schema. It does not directly create MongoDB ObjectIds; rather, it is used to define the structure of a path in a Mongoose schema.

On the other hand, `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` is a type that represents the BSON ObjectId value itself.

Src: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

> A SchemaType is different from a type. In other words, mongoose.ObjectId !== mongoose.Types.ObjectId. A SchemaType is just a configuration object for Mongoose. An instance of the mongoose.ObjectId SchemaType doesn't actually create MongoDB ObjectIds, it is just a configuration for a path in a schema.